# Does "I rinsed off the vegetables" imply that I already washed the vegetables a few times earlier and now I just rinsed them?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

This dictionary says "**to rinse**: *to wash (something) with clean water and without soap*".

When looking at my washing machine, I see that it has 2 functions:

> -1st, Wash
>
> -2nd, Rinse

That lead me to think about the meaning of the verb "**rinse**".

First, we always wash things with clean water, no-one uses dirty water.

Second, say I have very dirty vegetables and I have to wash them at **least 3 times** of course with clean water to make them clean.

Do we say "**I rinsed off the vegetables 3 times**"?

Or does "**I rinsed off the vegetables**" imply that I already washed the vegetables a few times (maybe twice) earlier and now I just rinsed them (meaning wash the the last time) to make them clean?

Dictionaries lack the nuance of the words.

Comment: No. Washing machine rinses **out** soap. Rinsing vegetables rinses **off** dirt and possibly some insecticide if it's not organically grown. There's no sense that you've previously washed or previosuly rinsed the vegetables.  Consult some better dictionaries.  E.g. https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rinse#:~:text=%3A%20to%20cleanse%20(as%20of%20soap,lightly%20or%20in%20water%20only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *rinse cycle* of your washing machine uses plain water to get the detergent out of the clothes. You *rinse* your hands after washing them with soap.

I don't suppose that you use soap to get the soil off your vegetables, just plain/clean water, so you could either call it *washing* them or *rinsing* them.